# persistence exception on database connection using glassfish

Tags: mysql, glassfish, persistence

I'm new to glass-fish & persistence and while trying to run a query on MySQL database in my machine i get the following error:

> Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
>   Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: No database selected
>   Error Code: 1046

before running the server i made sure that the server configuration are done using this guide : [mysql site manual for using connector with glassfish](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-glassfish-config.html), and configured my persistence.xml like this:

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="StudentRecipieWebsite" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <non-jta-data-source>jdbc/mySql</non-jta-data-source>
    <class>il.musehunter.studentRecipes.dbModel.Image</class>
    <class>il.musehunter.studentRecipes.dbModel.Ingrediant</class>
    <class>il.musehunter.studentRecipes.dbModel.Recipe</class>
    <class>il.musehunter.studentRecipes.dbModel.User</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/recipes_data"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="moshe1475"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing" value="JDBC"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I'm really new to this and does not have a clue to what i should do next so any help would be very appreciated.

edit:

adding part of the domain.xml from my glassfish server  :

```
<applications>
<application context-root="/StudentRecipieWebsite" location="${com.sun.aas.instanceRootURI}/applications/StudentRecipieWebsite/" name="StudentRecipieWebsite" object-type="user">
  <property name="appLocation" value="${com.sun.aas.instanceRootURI}/applications/__internal/StudentRecipieWebsite/StudentRecipieWebsite.war"></property>
  <property name="org.glassfish.ejb.container.application_unique_id" value="89812698949156864"></property>
  <property name="org.glassfish.persistence.app_name_property" value="StudentRecipieWebsite"></property>
  <property name="defaultAppName" value="StudentRecipieWebsite"></property>
  <module name="StudentRecipieWebsite">
    <engine sniffer="ejb"></engine>
    <engine sniffer="security"></engine>
    <engine sniffer="jpa"></engine>
    <engine sniffer="web"></engine>
  </module>
</application>
```

and:

```
<resources>
<jdbc-resource pool-name="__TimerPool" jndi-name="jdbc/__TimerPool" object-type="system-admin"></jdbc-resource>
<jdbc-resource pool-name="DerbyPool" jndi-name="jdbc/__default"></jdbc-resource>
<jdbc-connection-pool datasource-classname="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedXADataSource" res-type="javax.sql.XADataSource" name="__TimerPool">
  <property name="databaseName" value="${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/lib/databases/ejbtimer"></property>
  <property name="connectionAttributes" value=";create=true"></property>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
<jdbc-connection-pool is-isolation-level-guaranteed="false" datasource-classname="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDataSource" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" name="DerbyPool">
  <property name="PortNumber" value="1527"></property>
  <property name="Password" value="APP"></property>
  <property name="User" value="APP"></property>
  <property name="serverName" value="localhost"></property>
  <property name="DatabaseName" value="sun-appserv-samples"></property>
  <property name="connectionAttributes" value=";create=true"></property>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
<jdbc-connection-pool datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" name="MySQLConnPool">
  <property name="portNumber" value="3306"></property>
  <property name="databaseName" value="recipes_data"></property>
  <property name="serverName" value="localhost"></property>
  <property name="user" value="root"></property>
  <property name="password" value="moshe1475"></property>
  <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://:3306/"></property>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
<jdbc-resource pool-name="MySQLConnPool" description="" jndi-name="jdbc/mySql"></jdbc-resource></resources>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first guess is that the connection URL in the data source definition is not quite right because "No database selected Error Code: 1046" is a MySQL error.

You do not need to configure the data source in `persistence.xml` if you have already defined a data source in your application server (which is the common way). Can you post the data source definition from your `$GLASSFISH_HOME/glassfish/domains/$GLASSFISH_DOMAIN/config/domain.xml`?

This is an example persistence.xml I took from an project of mine (more or less from the Netbeans template) that might help you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

  <persistence-unit name="MyPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/sample</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
       <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Good luck!

Answering to the comment:

You need to add the database name to the URL:

```
<property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://nameOrIPOfYourServerOrLocalhost:3306/nameOfYourDatabase"></property>
```

That should resolve the problem.

Comment: hi jens and thank you for helping me!  i added some of the domain.xml file which a believe is relevant (the whole file is very large).   i don't know a thing about configuring persistence and glassfish and only did what i sew on the tutorials, so this xml snippet you gave me doesn't help me because i don't know which attributes i should add...   all i know is i am stuck with this for a week now so any help would be very appreciated

Comment: Added suggestion to my answer.

Comment: at last!! :) you were correct except that instead of addeing property as: jdbc:mysql://nameOrIPOfYourServerOrLocalhost:3306/nameOfYourDatabase  i had to add the url without the jdbc prefix like this: nameOrIPOfYourServerOrLocalhost:3306/nameOfYourDatabase and it worked!   many many thanks

Comment: FYI my Glassfish 3.1 admin console has two different properties "Url" and "URL". Can't imagine why this makes sense but I had this problem because I had only changed the first one to include the database name, and had to change both of them.